# Sending to multiple nodes using UDP while retaining the same source port

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

Is there an easier or less costly way of being able to send UDP datagrams to multiple nodes from a single sender without calling `.Dispose()` on `UdpClient` and then re-issuing the `.Connect(string ip, int port)` command?

```cs
private UdpClient _UdpClient = new UdpClient(8000);

public void Send(string ip, int port, byte[] data)
{ 
    _UdpClient.Dispose();
    _UdpClient = new UdpClient(_Port);
    _UdpClient.Connect(ip, port);
    _UdpClient.Send(data, data.Length);
}
```

I've tried simply calling the third and fourth lines in the `Send` method, i.e. `.Connect(ip, port)` and `.Send(data, data.Length)` without disposing and reinstantiating `_UdpClient`, because the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.connect?view=netcore-3.1) states that:

> If you want to send datagrams to a different remote host, you must make another call to the Connect method or create another UdpClient without a default remote host.

I can't use another `UdpClient` because I can only bind one instance of `UdpClient` to the desired source port.  If I try to use a new `UdpClient` each time, I naturally and expectedly get this exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient..ctor(Int32 port, AddressFamily family)
   at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient..ctor(Int32 port)
```

My code above works; I'm doubting that `.Dispose()` and reinstantiating are very heavy, I mean it is UDP and not TCP, but I just **feel dirty** writing the code this way.

When I try to just use `.Connect(ip, port)` and not use `.Dispose()` and reinstantiating, I get behavior contrary to the document.  It sends the datagram to the `ip, port` defined in the previous `.Connect(ip, port)` (very strange).

Environment is Windows 10, .NET Core 3.1.

--- Edit with Solution ---

```cs
private UdpClient _UdpClient = new UdpClient(8000);

public void Send(string ip, int port, byte[] data)
{ 
    IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
    _UdpClient.Send(data, data.Length, ipe);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Connect()`.

UDP is not a connection-oriented protocol in the first place. In spite of this, the `Connect()` method is supported for `UDP` sockets, as far as I can tell, simply for convenience. In simple scenarios, calling `Connect()` once is simpler than having to keep passing the remote endpoint address with each call, and it also has the effect of filtering inbound traffic. These can *in some cases* make the code easier.

But in your case, it's not making things easier. So don't use it. There are `Send()` and `Receive()` overloads that allow you to specify the remote endpoint for each send, and obtain the remote endpoint for each receive.

If you can use the `Socket` class, that class provides `SendTo()` and `ReceiveFrom()` methods for the same purpose. `UdpClient` is just a thin wrapper around `Socket`, so often that's an easier/preferable way to go anyway.

As long as you don't call `Connect()`, you should not run into the problems you're seeing.